# add multi level xml powershell

Tags: .net, xml, powershell

I'm trying to create some multi level xml in powershell. I started with the code from

[adding XML sub-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987318/powershell-adding-xml-sub-elements)

I'm having trouble getting my head around how to create a second sublevel. An example of the xml I want to create is below.

Thanks in advance,

Goldstien

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svcengine SYSTEM "service.dtd">

<Services>

<Service>
<Name>My service</Name>
<Label>Availability</Label>
<Source>
    <Composition/>
    <ServiceRef>My service ref</ServiceRef>
</Source>
</Service>

</Services>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "create a second sublevel". Do you want to modify the structure? For that you'd have to change the DTD. Or do you just want to append a child node to some node? That would be done like this (in general): select a node, create a new element, append the new element to the selected node.

Comment: So within the Service tag are the source tag and children. I am having trouble adapting the code from the previous post to produce that xml code above. I'm familiar with powershell but new to xml coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a structure like this:

```
<Services>
  <Service>
    <Name>My service</Name>
    <Label>Availability</Label>
  </Service>
</Services>
```

and want to add a node `<Source>` so that it looks like this:

```
<Services>
  <Service>
    <Name>My service</Name>
    <Label>Availability</Label>
    <Source>
      <Composition/>
      <ServiceRef>My service ref</ServiceRef>
    </Source>
  </Service>
</Services>
```

you could go about it like this:

```
# load XML file
[xml]$doc = Get-Content "C:\service.xml"

# create node <Composition>
$comp = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'Composition', '')

# create node <ServiceRef>
$sref = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'ServiceRef', '')
$desc = $doc.CreateTextNode('My service ref')
$sref.AppendChild($desc)

# create node <Source> and append child nodes <Composition> and <ServiceRef>
$src = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'Source', '')
$src.AppendChild($comp)
$src.AppendChild($sref)

# append node <Source> to node <Service>
$svc = $doc.SelectSingleNode('//Service')
$svc.AppendChild($src)

# save XML file
$doc.Save("C:\service.xml")
```

**Edit:** You can loop over several `<Service>` nodes with something like this (simplified):

```
$doc.SelectNodes('//Service') | % {
  $comp = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'Composition', '')
  $sref = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'ServiceRef', '')

  $src = $doc.CreateNode('element', 'Source', '')
  $src.AppendChild($comp)
  $src.AppendChild($sref)

  $_.AppendChild($src)
}
```

Comment: Thanks - moving closer. So I manually created C:\service.xml and ran the new code and this works. I have several services in an array (i.e $services=@("service1","service2") and was wondering how to loop through them.