# Add xml object to xml file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create an RDCMan file (.rdg xml file) using PowerShell. I have started by defining this template

```
$newFileTemplate = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RDCMan programVersion="2.7" schemaVersion="3">
    <file>       
    <properties>
        <expanded>False</expanded>
        <name>Office Servers</name>
    </properties>    
    <displaySettings inherit="None">
        <liveThumbnailUpdates>True</liveThumbnailUpdates>
        <allowThumbnailSessionInteraction>False</allowThumbnailSessionInteraction>
        <showDisconnectedThumbnails>True</showDisconnectedThumbnails>
        <thumbnailScale>1</thumbnailScale>
        <smartSizeDockedWindows>True</smartSizeDockedWindows>
        <smartSizeUndockedWindows>False</smartSizeUndockedWindows>
    </displaySettings>
    </file>
</RDCMan>
'
```

before creating an xml object like so

```
$File = 'D:\Test.rdg'
Set-Content $File $newFileTemplate
[XML]$XMLFile = [XML](Get-Content $File)
```

I would then like to define a function for adding a group of servers

```
# This function adds a new group element
Function Add-NewGroup($GroupName,$RDCManFile) {
    [xml]$GroupXML = @"
    <group>
      <properties>
        <expanded>False</expanded>
        <name>$GroupName</name>
      </properties>
    </group>
"@
    $Child = $RDCManFile.ImportNode($GroupXML.group, $true)
    $RDCManFile.Configuration.AppendChild($Child)
}
```

And call it by running

```
Add-NewGroup('DCs',$XMLFile)
```

This would allow me to populate the xml file with all of the OUs in AD.
Is anyone able to tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Update: The error I am getting is

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\Users\user\Desktop\Projects\RDCMan\Create-RDG.ps1:179 char:5
+     $Child = $RDCManFile.ImportNode($GroupXML.group, $true)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\Users\user\Desktop\Projects\RDCMan\Create-RDG.ps1:180 char:5
+     $RDCManFile.Configuration.AppendChild($Child)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

And I am trying to do what was suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29693625/2165019

Comment: What kind of output are you receiving? Are you getting errors?  It's hard to say where you're going wrong if we don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Hi @AutomatedOrder thanks for having a look at this. I have updated the description for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *The property 'Configuration' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.* error at `$RDCManFile.Configuration.AppendChild($Child)`.

If I can accept a `.rdg` file format and structure as defined in the [*Script to create a Remote Desktop Connection Manager group from Active Directory*](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Script-to-create-a-Remote-831a1b20) Technet article then I'd use

```
$RDCManFile.RDCMan.file.AppendChild($Child)
```

2. Follow the [Theo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62342905/3439404) about calling a function.

Pass parameters as positional

```
Add-NewGroup 'DCs' $XMLFile
```

or as named

```
Add-NewGroup -GroupName 'DCs' -RDCManFile $XMLFile
```

Comment: Hi JosefZ thank you so much for your suggestions! I can confirm that the script is now working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error (and second) most likely means that `$RDCManFile` is null.

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\Users\user\Desktop\Projects\RDCMan\Create-RDG.ps1:179 char:5
+     $Child = $RDCManFile.ImportNode($GroupXML.group, $true)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Try adding `$RDCManFile | Out-Host` at the top of the `Add-NewGroup` function to check what's contained in that variable.

Comment: Hi Cbsch it looks like the problem was related to me calling the function wrong. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you are calling the function.

Because of the comma in between the parameters, PowerShell sees this as one array value, so only parameter `$GroupName` will receive something.

Furthermore, you should not use brackets around the params, call the function like this:

```
Add-NewGroup 'DCs' $XMLFile
```

or send the parameters using their names:

```
Add-NewGroup -GroupName 'DCs' -RDCManFile $XMLFile
```